# When adding an image to TinyMCE is there a way to get the editing area to expand down automatically?

Tags: tinymce

When I add an image to TinyMCE the image gets added ok, but it is severely cut off in editing view until you manually expand the editing window by dragging the bottom-right.

Is there a way to get TinyMCE to automatically expand as needed when adding images?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the autoresize plugin docs and tried it and it works for my purpose now, because when editing the area initializes to show the entire content. I see there are other options for this as well here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource